# Spring guide example for messaging with JMS failing

Tags: jms, spring-jms

I have implemented the example for messaging with JMS using Spring's JMSTemplate as it is.

https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-jms/tree/master/complete

But getting following error.

Please clarify.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-messaging-jms</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Error Log**

```
omkar@omkar-PC:~/Labs/Practice/workspace/gs-messaging-jms$ mvn spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building gs-messaging-jms 0.1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ gs-messaging-jms >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:resources (default-resources) @ gs-messaging-jms ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ gs-messaging-jms ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ gs-messaging-jms ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ gs-messaging-jms ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ gs-messaging-jms <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ gs-messaging-jms ---

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.3.RELEASE)

2018-07-07 15:39:47.070  INFO 10248 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on omkar-PC with PID 10248 (/home/omkar/Labs/Practice/workspace/gs-messaging-jms/target/classes started by omkar in /home/omkar/Labs/Practice/workspace/gs-messaging-jms)
2018-07-07 15:39:47.078  INFO 10248 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-07-07 15:39:47.157  INFO 10248 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@611d79ac: startup date [Sat Jul 07 15:39:47 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-07-07 15:39:47.892  WARN 10248 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'receiver' defined in file [/home/omkar/Labs/Practice/workspace/gs-messaging-jms/target/classes/hello/Receiver.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myFactory' defined in hello.Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'myFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
2018-07-07 15:39:47.906  INFO 10248 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-07 15:39:48.054 ERROR 10248 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method myFactory in hello.Application required a bean of type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' that could not be found.
        - Bean method 'connectionFactory' not loaded because AnyNestedCondition 0 matched 2 did not; NestedCondition on JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.JndiOrPropertyCondition.Property @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.jms.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'; NestedCondition on JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.JndiOrPropertyCondition.Jndi @ConditionalOnJndi JNDI environment is not available


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' in your configuration.

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:496)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'receiver' defined in file [/home/omkar/Labs/Practice/workspace/gs-messaging-jms/target/classes/hello/Receiver.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myFactory' defined in hello.Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'myFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:589)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
        at hello.Application.main(Application.java:44)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myFactory' defined in hello.Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'myFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1256)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
        at org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.processJmsListener(JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
        at org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$null$1(JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:240)
        at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
        at org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessAfterInitialization$2(JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:239)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
        at org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(JmsListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:238)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:439)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1712)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724)
        ... 38 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.206 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-07T15:39:48+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/275M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You need to show your POM; perhaps you are missing a dependency?

Comment: Updated the question with pom.xml.